# Any finite set of non-collinear points on a plane determines a circle that does not contain other points in the interior

Tags: geometry, circles

> On a plane we have finite amount of points. Any three of them are not collinear.  Show that there exist circle (formed with three or more points) that doesn't contain other points in it.

Source: a national mathematics magazine.

My approach:

Assume we have some circle created from 3 or more points. 
If in this circle (interior) exists some point, we take any two points from the border and one from the inside and create new circle.

And we can repeat it until we have circle without inner points.

Does this work?

Comment: What if the 4 points are in a square arrangement?  The (unique) circle through any three automatically contains the 4th, right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JasonDeVito But no points *in* it (as there are only these four point. Note that "... formed with three or more points ..." refers to the points *on* the circle.

Comment: Do you mean to say "there exists a circle passing through three of the points such that none of the points _lies in the interior_ of that circle? Normally "lying in a circle" isn't meaningful, and most readers will take it to be a mistyping of "lying on a circle".

Comment: Assuming my interpretation is right, your "proof" doesn't work, since with the point inside the circle and the points on the circle (which are the only points in your set that you know anything about) you _cannot_ create a new circle that is entirely contained in the interior of original circle.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think he means no points in the interior.

Comment: @All:  Thanks for the clarification.  Indeed I did read it as lying "on" the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is wrong. You assume that if $D$ is inside the circle circumscribing $ABC$ then one of the circles circumscribing $ABD$, $BCD$, or $ACD$ is inside the original circle. That is far from obvious, and actually false.

And, as noted by Henning in comments, it is absolutely false. When $D$ is in the interior of the circle circumscribing $ABC$, none of the circles circumscribing $D$ and two of the points in the triangle are contained in the original circle.

Comment: If is not only false, it is so false that it is _never true_. If $D$ is _any_ point in the interior of _any_ triangle $ABC$, then the circumcircle of $ABD$ _will_ extend outside the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that it was actually absolutely false. It is obviously false that you can take any triangle to get a "smaller" circle, because if $D$ was very close to $AB$ then the circle containing $ABC$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the given finite set. The convex hull of $S$ is a convex polygon $P$ whose vertices are elements of $S$. Take any two subsequent vertices $p$, $q$ of $P$. The line $g:=p\vee q$ is a supporting line of $S$, i.e., on one side $G^+$ of $g$ there are no points of $S$. Let $h$ be the median line of $p$ and $q$, and consider all circles with center $m\in h$ that go through $p$ and $q$. When $m$ is in $G^+$ and far away  of $g$ then the circle will contain no points of $S$ in its interior. Now move $m$ along $h$ to the other side of $g$ and beyond. When $m$ is far away on the other side of $g$ then the circle will contain all points of $S$ (other than $p$ and $q$) in its interior. There has to  be a moment in between where the "morphing" circle has still no points of $S$ in its interior, but $\geq3$ points on its boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Take the [Delauney tesselation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of the point set. Every face in this tessellation contains points that lie on a circle, such that there is no other point inside. So every face gives you a set of points that satisfies your constraint.

The tessellation can be computed quite easily. Assign for every point $p_i=(x_i,y_i)$  a height $z_i=x_i^2+y_i^2$. The lower convex hull of the induced 3d point set projects down to the Delaunay tessellation.